# etoolbox's iftoggle vs verbatim

Tags: conditionals, verbatim, etoolbox

My problem is that I can set up toggles, using etoolbox's `\newtoggle{x}`, set it to true with `\toggletrue{x}` and even use it with `iftoggle{x}{this for true}{this for false}`. However, if I try to put a `verbatim` environment inside a conditional block, it breaks and gives me an error message:

```
Runaway argument?
 for x in range(1, 43): print('x=', x) \end {verbatim} 
./q4.tex:19: Paragraph ended before \@xverbatim was complete.
<to be read again> )
./Quiz1.tex:90: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.90 \vspace{
             1 pc} 
? 
                   \par 
l.19 }{}

?
```

for the code:

```
\iftoggle{displaysolutions}{

\textit{The statement will execute y times.}
\begin{verbatim}
for x in range(0, y):
    print('x=', x)
\end{verbatim}

}{}
```

Any ideas of what I'm possibly doing wrong? Any alternatives?

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any idea of an alternative?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having a `verbatim` environment in the argument to another command is not allowed: the changes that need to be done to the special characters' meaning can't be made when the environment has already been read in as an argument.

A way out is adapting to use a "primitive" syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iftoggleverb}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{etb@tgl@#1}
    {\csname etb@tgl@#1\endcsname\iftrue\iffalse}
    {\etb@noglobal\etb@err@notoggle{#1}\iffalse}%
}
\makeatother

\newtoggle{displaysolutions}
\togglefalse{displaysolutions}

\begin{document}
\section{A}

Are solutions displayed? \iftoggle{displaysolutions}{Yes}{No}.

\iftoggleverb{displaysolutions}

\noindent\textit{The statement will execute y times.}
\begin{verbatim}
for x in range(0, y):
    print('x=', x)
\end{verbatim}

\fi


\toggletrue{displaysolutions}

\section{B}

Are solutions displayed? \iftoggle{displaysolutions}{Yes}{No}.

\iftoggleverb{displaysolutions}

\noindent\textit{The statement will execute y times.}
\begin{verbatim}
for x in range(0, y):
    print('x=', x)
\end{verbatim}

\fi

\end{document}
```

There should be a "matching `\fi`" after the part you want displayed or not.

You can also use

```
\iftoggleverb{displaysolutions}
<material to be displayed if the toggle is true>
\else
<material to be displayed if the toggle is false>
\fi
```

[image]

***Important limitation.*** Don't use `\iftoggleverb` nested in other conditional statements.

Comment: Perfect! This is precisely what I needed!