# How to make a package using sagetex and sage-commands

Tags: macros, package-writing, sagetex

I am trying to make my own package building on `sagetex`. It starts with

```
\RequirePackage{sagetex}
```

and I want it to execute some 'sagesilent' code as for instance

```
\newcommand{\loadsagefunction}{
\begin{sagesilent}
def listofpoints(xlist,ylist):
    A=matrix([xlist,ylist])
    return A.transpose()
\end{sagesilent}
}
```

The above code doesn't work since it is NOT possible to place the 'sagesilent' environment inside a `\newcommand` as far as I know from what I have read in different places.

I am looking for some nice way to execute 'sagesilent' code from a package I make myself. The point here is that I want to use my self-defined sage-commands in many different LaTeX-documents so it would be much nicer and cleaner to have a package than to spread around a file called `mysagefunctions.tex` and use

```
\input{mysagefunctions}
```

Any nice suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) see there is [`sagetex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetexpackage.pdf) package made available at ctan.org

Comment: Please complete your code snippets into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Do you really need to load code on a function-by-function basis?  If not, you could just have the `sagesilent` in your input file.  Or maybe break up your code into a few different input files, based on the functionality provided.  In terms of toggling `sagesilent`, [this might be useful](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78684/etoolboxs-iftoggle-vs-verbatim).

Comment: @LaRiFaRi That is hardly a reason to close a question.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi That's not our call. Somebody might need this later. It is a perfectly viable question. With proper explanation. The questions in the comments are secondary nature. But probably it will be closed because of your vote.

Comment: I don't understand why it would be "much nicer and cleaner" to use "\usepackage{foo}" instead of "\input{foo}". Either way, you have code in a separate file and have to do something in your tex file to get it to read that file.

Comment: Also, your example makes it look like what you're *really* doing is building up a library of Sage functions. So perhaps what you really want is a mysagefunctions.py file, which you put somewhere where Sage can find it, and then do "from mysagefunctions import foo, bar, etc" in a sagesilent environment in your document.